# Excel - Compare two whole numbers and return a value if there is a +-$1 change

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns of prices.  I need to flag which prices are off by +-$1.  I have tried =IF(ABS((B2-A2)/A2)<1, "True", "False") which works except I don't want a percentage - I specifically need the $1 amount.

Comment: =IF(SUM(A52-B52)>1, "difference","ok") also works but only works if the result is a positive number. I need to see a negative difference as well.

Comment: Think I answered my own question!                                                          =IF((OR(A2-B2>1,A2-B2<-1)),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: You can do it even simpler: `=OR(A2-B2>1,A2-B2<-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt was very close – just don't divide by A2:

```
=IF(ABS(B2-A2)<1, "True", "False")
```

Excel automatically returns TRUE or FALSE for comparisons, so you don't need to wrap it in an `IF` function:

```
=ABS(B2-A2)<1
```

[image]